# How to change/customize Crosshair Overlays for JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to use a crosshair overlay for an XYPlot. This works quite well, though I would like to change the way the label is drawn. This is my current snippet:

```
// add crosshair
final CrosshairOverlay crosshairOverlay = new CrosshairOverlay();
final Crosshair xCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.DARK_GRAY, new BasicStroke(0f));
xCrosshair.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f));
xCrosshair.setLabelOutlineVisible(false);
xCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
xCrosshair.setLabelGenerator(new CrosshairLabelGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String generateLabel(final Crosshair ch) {
        return UnitConverter.freq2Str(ch.getValue());
    }
});

final Crosshair yCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.DARK_GRAY, new BasicStroke(0f));
yCrosshair.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f));
yCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
yCrosshair.setLabelOutlineVisible(false);
yCrosshair.setLabelGenerator(new CrosshairLabelGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String generateLabel(final Crosshair ch) {
        return UnitConverter.val2Str(ch.getValue(), 5, "dBc/Hz");
    }
});

crosshairOverlay.addDomainCrosshair(xCrosshair);
crosshairOverlay.addRangeCrosshair(yCrosshair);
this.addOverlay(crosshairOverlay);
this.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(final ChartMouseEvent event) {
        final Rectangle2D dataArea = APChartPanel.this.getScreenDataArea();
        final XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) event.getChart().getPlot();
        final double x = plot.getDomainAxis().java2DToValue(event.getTrigger().getX(), dataArea, RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
        final double y = plot.getRangeAxis().java2DToValue(event.getTrigger().getY(), dataArea, RectangleEdge.LEFT);
        xCrosshair.setValue(x);
        yCrosshair.setValue(y);
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(final ChartMouseEvent arg0) {}
});
```

This results in the following labels:

[image: current labels]

As a start, I would like to remove the box around the text and would like to control the font size and family. But using `Crosshair#setLabelOutlineVisible(boolean)` will also remove the text and  `Crosshair#setLabelFont(Font)` doesn't change the font at all. Is this still work in progress or am I doing something wrong here?

---

I got to the following solution:

[image: final result]

by extending `CrosshairOverlay` with the suggestions of @trashgod and using this code for an individual crosshair:

```
final Crosshair yCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.GRAY, new BasicStroke(0f));
yCrosshair.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.7f));
yCrosshair.setLabelPaint(Color.GRAY);
yCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
yCrosshair.setLabelOutlineVisible(false);
yCrosshair.setLabelFont(yCrosshair.getLabelFont().deriveFont(11f));
yCrosshair.setLabelGenerator(new CrosshairLabelGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String generateLabel(final Crosshair ch) {
        return UnitConverter.val2Str(ch.getValue(), 5, "dBc/Hz");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CrosshairOverlay`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/panel/CrosshairOverlay.html) method [`drawVerticalCrosshair()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/panel/CrosshairOverlay.html#drawVerticalCrosshair-java.awt.Graphics2D-java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D-double-org.jfree.chart.plot.Crosshair-) renders the crosshair label, as shown [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/d2cc3fc846184313929ca121819ea6463e4ee787/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/panel/CrosshairOverlay.java#L317), but it previously used neither `Crosshair::isLabelOutlineVisible` nor `Crosshair::getLabelFont`. You might try something like this:

```
if (crosshair.isLabelOutlineVisible()) { g2.draw(hotspot); }
g2.setFont(crosshair.getLabelFont());
TextUtilities.drawAlignedString(label, g2, xx, yy, alignPt);
```

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180275/230513), I made the following changes to get the result shown.

```
xCrosshair.setLabelFont(xCrosshair.getLabelFont().deriveFont(20f));
xCrosshair.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f));
xCrosshair.setLabelOutlineVisible(false);
```

[image]

Similar code in `drawHorizontalCrosshair()` should also be updated; saving and restoring the graphics context's font may also be warranted.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I hoped that I was doing something wrong but it seems this is not completely finished yet (probably never will). But extending `CrosshairOverlay` was actually less intrusive than expected. I have added a screenshot of the result.

Comment: @brimborium: Glad it helped; a patch has been submitted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117824).