# How to show cross lines and red color for price drop in JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

My app is simplified below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.*;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.*;
import org.jfree.chart.panel.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;

public class PriceVolume_Chart extends JPanel implements ChartMouseListener    // A demo application for price-volume chart.   
{
  ChartPanel panel;
  TimeSeries Price_series=new TimeSeries("Price");
  TimeSeries Volume_Series=new TimeSeries("Volume");
  Crosshair xCrosshair,yCrosshair;
  
  public PriceVolume_Chart(String Symbol)
  {
    JFreeChart chart=createChart(Symbol);
    panel=new ChartPanel(chart,true,true,true,false,true);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000,500));
    panel.addChartMouseListener(this);
    CrosshairOverlay crosshairOverlay=new CrosshairOverlay();
    xCrosshair=new Crosshair(Double.NaN,Color.GRAY,new BasicStroke(0f));
    xCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
    yCrosshair=new Crosshair(Double.NaN,Color.GRAY,new BasicStroke(0f));
    yCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
    crosshairOverlay.addDomainCrosshair(xCrosshair);
    crosshairOverlay.addRangeCrosshair(yCrosshair);
    panel.addOverlay(crosshairOverlay);
    add(panel);
  }

  private JFreeChart createChart(String Symbol)
  {
    createPriceDataset(Symbol);
    XYDataset priceData=new TimeSeriesCollection(Price_series);
    JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(Symbol,
                                                        "Date",
                                                        getYLabel("Price ( $ )"),
                                                        priceData,
                                                        true,
                                                        true,
                                                        true
                                                       );
    XYPlot plot=chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(192,196,196));
    NumberAxis rangeAxis1=(NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis1.setLowerMargin(0.40);                                           // Leave room for volume bars
//    plot.getRenderer().setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT,DateFormat.getDateInstance(), NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()));
    plot.getRenderer().setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d"),NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()));
//    DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("00.00");
//    rangeAxis1.setNumberFormatOverride(format);
//    rangeAxis1.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());  

    NumberAxis rangeAxis2=new NumberAxis("Volume");
    rangeAxis2.setUpperMargin(1.00);                                           // Leave room for price line   
    rangeAxis2.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
    plot.setRangeAxis(1,rangeAxis2);
    plot.setDataset(1,new TimeSeriesCollection(Volume_Series));
    plot.setRangeAxis(1,rangeAxis2);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1,1);
    XYBarRenderer renderer2=new XYBarRenderer(0.20);
    renderer2.setShadowVisible(false);
    renderer2.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d"),new DecimalFormat("0,000")));
    plot.setRenderer(1,renderer2);
    return chart;
  }

  private void createPriceDataset(String Symbol)
  {
    String Lines[]=new String[21],Items[],Date;
    int Year,Month,Day;
    long Volume;
    double Price;

    Lines[0]="Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume";
    Lines[1]="2019-09-23,129.589996,130.710007,128.240005,129.300003,126.555969,553700";
    Lines[2]="2019-09-24,129.309998,129.529999,125.500000,126.750000,124.060089,732900";
    Lines[3]="2019-09-25,126.570000,128.500000,126.190002,127.879997,125.166100,422000";
    Lines[4]="2019-09-26,127.849998,128.589996,127.169998,127.779999,125.068230,376100";
    Lines[5]="2019-09-27,128.669998,129.289993,126.389999,126.419998,123.737083,332900";
    Lines[6]="2019-09-30,126.589996,128.789993,125.849998,128.130005,125.410797,456700";
    Lines[7]="2019-10-01,129.039993,130.899994,125.480003,126.040001,123.365158,322700";
    Lines[8]="2019-10-02,125.059998,125.180000,121.620003,123.120003,120.507126,577100";
    Lines[9]="2019-10-03,122.650002,123.320000,119.089996,122.559998,119.959007,581300";
    Lines[10]="2019-10-04,122.970001,123.949997,121.320000,123.879997,121.250992,315700";
    Lines[11]="2019-10-07,123.139999,124.610001,122.669998,122.879997,120.272217,510300";
    Lines[12]="2019-10-08,121.720001,121.879997,118.089996,118.660004,116.141777,616600";
    Lines[13]="2019-10-09,119.410004,119.610001,116.680000,118.419998,115.906868,603300";
    Lines[14]="2019-10-10,119.089996,121.209999,117.080002,118.209999,115.701324,483300";
    Lines[15]="2019-10-11,120.330002,123.040001,119.720001,122.550003,119.949226,700500";
    Lines[16]="2019-10-14,122.550003,123.720001,120.940002,122.540001,119.939430,492900";
    Lines[17]="2019-10-15,122.849998,124.220001,121.230003,123.699997,121.074814,598200";
    Lines[18]="2019-10-16,123.889999,124.849998,122.800003,123.209999,120.595207,663600";
    Lines[19]="2019-10-17,123.449997,124.889999,122.790001,123.360001,120.742035,563200";
    Lines[20]="2019-10-18,123.050003,124.620003,122.459999,123.540001,120.918213,650300";
    
    for (int i=1;i<Lines.length;i++)
    {
      Items=Lines[i].split(",");
      Date=Items[0].replace("-0","-");
      Price=Double.parseDouble(Items[5]);
      Volume=Long.parseLong(Items[6]);
      Items=Date.split("-");
      Year=Integer.parseInt(Items[0]);
      Month=Integer.parseInt(Items[1]);
      Day=Integer.parseInt(Items[2]);
      Price_series.add(new Day(Day,Month,Year),Price);
      Volume_Series.add(new Day(Day,Month,Year),Volume);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event)
  {
    // ignore
  }

  public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent cmevent)
  {
    ChartEntity chartentity=cmevent.getEntity();
    if (chartentity instanceof XYItemEntity)
    {
      XYItemEntity e=(XYItemEntity)chartentity;
      XYDataset d=e.getDataset();
      int s=e.getSeriesIndex();
      int i=e.getItem();
      double x=d.getXValue(s,i);
      double y=d.getYValue(s,i);
      this.xCrosshair.setValue(x);
      this.yCrosshair.setValue(y);
    }
  }
  String getYLabel(String Text)
  {
    String Result="";
    
    for (int i=0;i<Text.length();i++) Result+=Text.charAt(i)+(i<Text.length()-1?"\u2009":"");
//    Out(Result);
    return Result;
  }

  private static void out(String message) { System.out.print(message); }
  private static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  // Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
  static void Create_And_Show_GUI()
  {
    final PriceVolume_Chart demo=new PriceVolume_Chart("ADS");

    JFrame frame=new JFrame("PriceVolume_Chart Frame");
    frame.add(demo);
    frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); }
      public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { demo.repaint(); }
      public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) { demo.repaint(); }
      public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowOpening(WindowEvent e) { demo.repaint(); }
      public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }
      public void windowResized(WindowEvent e) { demo.repaint(); }
      public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) { demo.repaint(); }
    });
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread : creating and showing this application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { Create_And_Show_GUI(); } });
  }
}
```

=====================================================================

With the help of @trashgod I was able to add the cross-hair to the chart. However I still want to know how to achieve the following :

```
 [1] The value shown for volume when cross-hair moves, is in-correct, how to show correct volume value ?
 [2] How to have solid non-transparent background for the dynamic values shown near the axis ? Now it's transparent, hard to read.
 [3] How to set the cross-hair at startup on a certain [ e.g. 20th ] date ?
 [4] How to show red color for volumes when price drops ?
```

Here is an image of what I'm looking for :

[image]

Comment: You may be able to adapt the approach shown in [`CrosshairOverlayDemo1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180275/230513).

Comment: Very helpful, I've added that capability to my app, thanks. I've modified my question, still need help ^_^ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show cross lines when my mouse points to different locations on the image?

You were able to adapt the approach shown in [`CrosshairOverlayDemo1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180275/230513), suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106159/how-to-show-cross-lines-and-red-color-for-price-drop-in-jfreechart#comment113369054_64106159).

> The value shown for volume when cross-hair moves, is incorrect, how to show correct volume value?

Your implementation of `ChartMouseListener` accesses the *x* and *y* values from the price dataset. The *x* value is the date; the *y* value is the price. Absent formatting, the crosshair correctly displays the number of milliseconds from the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)). You probably want to fetch the corresponding volume.

> How to have solid non-transparent background for the dynamic values shown near the axis? Now it's transparent, hard to read.

You can modify the crosshair's appearance as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123308/230513). For the background, use an opaque color or specify an alpha value of 255 to construct a solid color.

> How to set the cross-hair at startup on a certain e.g. 20th date?

You can use `Robot`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231458/230513), but I prefer not to surprise the user in this way.

> How to show red color for volumes when price drops?

You can override `getItemPaint()`, as shown here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481556/230513) to change the rendered color as a function of the volume.

In general, you'll find it easier to examine such issues in isolated examples that can be integrated into your code, as you did with the crosshair overlay demo.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, I've solved most of the problems, but still have 2 more questions, I've asked them in another post ^_^ !