# Popup context menu throwing NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, popup, jfreechart

I implemented a dynamic `chart` with `JFreeChart`; but every time that I right-click, the `Popup` menu is trowing an error. If it is related to my code, the logger isn't showing to me, and I've no idea how to fix it.

Here is what the log points it out:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
    at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:126)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.<init>(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paint(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:501)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.paint(SynthMenuUI.java:280)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.update(SynthMenuUI.java:245)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This shows the Popup menu cropped:

[image: clipped]

and it should be like this:

[image: correct]

Anyone knows a solution or had the same issue?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the clipped context menu illustrated; verify that you construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); for more specific guidance, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem pictured; include OS and Java version.

Comment: I'm sorry for not answer you faster. I don't have access to the place where the `Popup` menu is constructed, because (I guess) the method is inside the constructor of the `ChartPanel`. I tried to manually create a new Popup, but it appears cropped too. This error might be caused when I create a `Class` that extends a `JPanel` and implements a `ChartMouseListener`, so I could set manually new `CrossairOverlay` every time a pass the mouse on the `chart`. I removed, and still doesn't work.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with [`CrosshairOverlayDemo1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180275/230513).