# Why some text has underline, but others don't in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have asked a few questions about JFreeChart before, so there is a [simple demp app](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/a3f7581417db19bf5b6dc52d3647a2f9), but I have noticed some text will have an underline, but others don't, as seen in the following image, why ? How to omit the underline ?

[image]

Here is a screenshot for the new version :

[image]

Here is the latest screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this with [tag:jfreechart] v1.5.3 under java 8, 11 or 17.

Comment: I switched to predefined colors; try it now.

Comment: I tried the new version, no change, see screenshot. I'm running JDK8 on Win7.

Comment: Odd that it's only some labels; you might try a different font size. None of the available L&Fs evinced the problem on Java 8, OS X, e.g. `-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`.

Comment: I tried "-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel", no difference. I also tried font size 16, different labels will have underline, some didn't have underline with size 14 will have underline at 16, others which had underline at 14 show no underline at 16.

Comment: How the the [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180275/230513) look? I think the default theme uses Tahoma; you might try a different font.

Comment: That demo looks correct, no underline. Why Tahoma sometimes has underline, sometimes doesn't ?

Comment: I pushed an update for minor issues. I've no idea why the underline varies with font size, but I never see it on macOS. Is it a Windows issue?

Comment: OK, maybe it's a Windows issue. I even tried it on the latest Win11 [ NT6.2 ], also got underline on some labels.

Comment: It looks like the light underline "disappears" when it coincides with the underlying   gridline; you might tinker with the `XYPlot` gridline paint. I pushed another update to normalize colors.

Comment: I thought so too, but it may not be for that reason, I just added the latest screenshots.

Comment: Your counter-example negates my hypothesis. I can't explain why `CrosshairOverlayDemo1` looks correct, but `PriceVolumeChart` doesn't.